# Utilizing a Django slug, getting a no reverse path error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

My apologies if you've already read a previous post I made about my Django slug problem. I cleaned up my old code, and perhaps have a better understanding of what I'm doing but I'm still lost as how to get a URL generated from a slug to work on my main landing page.

I'm working on a portfolio. I have a landing page where I'm going to link out to individual detail pages. I'm using get_absolute_url in my models to do this. When testing this out, I can get the link to work on the individual project detail page, but not on the main landing pages. Which is funny, because I don't need these links to work on the individual project pages. My guess is that something in my views is not set up correctly.

My views.py is set up like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, get_list_or_404
from .models import Project



def home(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'portfolio/home.html', {'projects': projects})

def individual_project_view(request, project_id):

    projectpage = get_list_or_404(Project, slug=project_id)
    return render(request, 'portfolio/project_detail.html',{'projectpage':projectpage})


def project_home(request):
    portfolioprojects = get_list_or_404(Project)
    return render(request, 'portfolio/project_detail.html', {'portfolioprojects':portfolioprojects})
```

And here is my urls.py for the individual landing pages, which are in a separate app.

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views



app_name = 'portfolio'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.project_home, name='project_home'),
    path('<slug:project_id>/', views.individual_project_view, name='individual_project'),
]
```

The urls.py in the root folder, is set up like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from portfolio import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('portfolio/', include('portfolio.urls'), name='portfolio'),



    ]
```

My models.py is set up like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Project(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='portfolio/images/')

    client = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 80, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField( blank=True)
    testimonial = models.TextField(blank=True)
    featuredimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='portfolio/images/', blank=True)
    type2 = models.CharField(max_length = 80, blank=True)
    description2 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    featuredimage2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='portfolio/images/', blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    url2 = models.URLField(blank=True)
    testimonial2 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    projecturl = models.URLField(blank=True)
    projecturl2 = models.URLField(blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    # u create url only here and then reference here throughout of your project
        return reverse('portfolio:individual_project',args=[self.slug])



    def __str__ (self):

        return self.project_name
```

And the HTML for the main landing page where I'm trying to access this link is as following:

```
  {% for project in projects %}

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6  padding_top">

    {% if project.url %}
    <a href="{{ project.url }}">
      <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" class="img-fluid  mb-2">

    </a>
    {% else %}


    <a href="{% url 'individual_project' project.slug %}">
    <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" class="img-fluid mb-2">
    </a>
```

When I try and access this template I get the following error:

" NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'individual_project' not found. 'individual_project' is not a valid view function or pattern name. "

What's really confusing me is that when I try this way of doing it with`<a href="{{project.get_absolute_url}}">` this works on the project detail template, which is headed by `{% for content in projectpage %}` but not on home.html which has the code `{% for project in projects %}`

thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show the url mapped for `individual_project_view` or the url with the name set to `individual_project`?

Comment: @bdbd Oh, just noticed I pasted in the same code twice. You'll find the URL mapping for individual_project_view in the second block of code (I just edited the post).

Thanks!!

Comment: Try to use `{% url 'portfolio:individual_project' project.slug %}`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @bdbd, unfortunately that produces the following error:

NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'individual_project' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['portfolio/(?P<project_id>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Comment: That means `project.slug` returned `''`. Just noticed you allow this field to be blank. Unfortunately that will fail in the url tag in this case. Maybe work with the primary key instead?